# Change Number of Div Elements in Row Based on Screen Size with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Is it possible to have different numbers of `<div>` elements depending on screen size with Bootstrap?

For example, 4 columns per row on desktops.

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| .col-md-3 | .col-md-3 | .col-md-3 | .col-md-3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| .col-md-3 | .col-md-3 | .col-md-3 | .col-md-3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Then instead of having each column span 100% on tablets and phones, have 3 columns per row on tablets. Pushing columns over 12 to the next row, like below.

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| .col-sm-4 | .col-sm-4 | .col-sm-4 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| .col-sm-4 | .col-sm-4 | .col-sm-4 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| .col-sm-4 | .col-sm-4 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I found Bootstrap's [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), where I can hide or show columns only for certain screen sizes. This would mean I have to repeat tons of the columns however (see snippet below), so I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm">
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-md visible-sm-4">
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm">
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm">
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-md visible-sm-4">
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-md visible-sm-4">
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I am aware, you cannot leave out the containing `.row` div. It would be nice to be able to just put `class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"` for all the elements and let bootstrap take however many `<div>`s to add up to 12. So 4 on medium screens, 3 on small screens, and 2 on extra small.

Comment: Note that I don't think the html snippet is working properly, but hopefully it illustrates what I mean about hiding a column and having a duplicate only made visible for certain screen sizes.

Comment: I'm not clear how what you're asking is different from default Grid behavior of simply specifying multiple `.col-*-*` breakpoints and containing more than 12 columns in a single `.row`.  See: https://www.bootply.com/Y6d9pZ12Pa

Comment: @RobertC My understanding was that you could specify multiple breakpoints to resize columns, but they still needed to add to 12 in one row. Such as this [W3 Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_medium&stacked=h), that has 2 colums. On desktop, they span 6 and 6. On smaller screens, it becomes 3 and 9.

Comment: @RobertC Based on what you've said and shown in your link, you can put columns exceed 12 in one row and bootstrap will automatically organize them into rows of 12?

Comment: @RobertC I think this question may be useful to others new to bootstrap. The W3 tutorial (and other sites) emphasize "Note that numbers in .col-*-* should always add up to 12 for each row." Obviously, that is not actually true. So if you want to write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per my comments in your original query, this is a misunderstanding of `.row`.  Per the Bootstrap Documents:

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You need only provide the various breakpoints in your layout and let Bootstrap handle the rest:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="well">1</div>
  </div> 
  
 </div>
</div>
```

I would note that I am using a `.well` here to display the full container size.  You may want to replace that with some custom wrapper, which may also necessitate additional code for margin/padding.